# Yii2: ActiveRecord with distinct query

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I need to write an ActiveRecord query where I get all fields of rows without duplicates in one field.

Example: Here is a table of books. I want to get all data of the rows with
distinct isbn. From duplicates the first row should be taken. The result should be the rows with id 1,2,4

```
id  | title   | isbn
--- | ------- | ------
1   | hello   | 1001
2   | world   | 1002
3   | this    | 1002
4   | is      | 1003
5   | funny   | 1003
```

My first attempt was

```
$books = Books::find()->select('isbn')->distinct()->all();
```

but that fills only the isbn field in `$books[0], $books[1], ...`.

Is this possible using Yii2 ActiveRecord?

Comment: The `select` method of `ActiveQuery` tells `Yii` what columns to choose select, so it's not what you need in this case. What do you wnat the query to do with the data in the other columns? So, if it's selected all the columns, and it's only returning distinct values of `isbn`, how should it handle the titles and `id`s?

Comment: I want to get $books filled with all fields for the ids 1, 2 and 4, e.g. $book[0]=[1,'hello', 1001],...  and not just the isdn field.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`groupBy()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#groupBy()-detail) for this:

```
$books = Books::find()->groupBy(['isbn'])->all();
```

But this returns random row with matching `isbn` value and may not work in some DBMS. Your requirements are too ambiguous to handle it in predictable way. But if you want always first row, you may use subquery to fetch matching `isbn` and `id`:

```
$query = (new Query())
    ->select(['MIN(id) as id, isbn'])
    ->from(Books::tableName())
    ->groupBy(['isbn']);
return Books::find()
    ->alias('book')
    ->innerJoin(['subquery' => $query], 'book.id = subquery.id AND book.id = subquery.id')
    ->all();
```

Answer (score -3):

The description given in Yii2 for the distinct property is as follows:

> Whether to select distinct rows of data only. If this is set true, the SELECT clause would be changed to SELECT DISTINCT.
>   -- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#$distinct-detail

therefore you should pass true with distinct property if you need to select the distinct values of 'isbn' as follows:

```
$books = Books::find()->select('isbn')->distinct(true)->all();
```